# Registry/System Tool like jv16 Power Tools 1.4

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I've been using the freeware version of the [jv16 Power Tools (1.4.x)](http://www.unleash.com/kurt/jv16powertools14/index.asp) for quite some time and it works great. It allows me to search the registry, do complete find/replace operations simply, scan down orphaned registry nodes or files, registry backups, etc. It doesn't do anything without asking and expects me to know how the registry works; it doesn't treat me like a simple user.

However, jv version 1.4 is getting long in the tooth and I'm not sure of its viability for Vista and Windows 7. I would upgrade, but the newer versions have switched away from the "here's a tool for someone who knows what they're doing" mindset to the "press this button to fix all your problems" mindset. I'd rather not use a program that's going to do things without my knowledge or permission. Also, I don't trust companies that say their software was the "[very best registry cleaning in both performance and accuracy of the products tested in this comparison study](http://www.macecraft.com/news/172/)", but the study was [conducted by employees](http://www.macecraft.com/registry_cleaner_comparison/).

I was wondering if anyone else used a similar (preferably open-source) program they'd like to recommend. Or, if you have experience with the newer versions of jv16 and would like to convince me, that works too.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the free tools [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) and [RevoUninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) for some time with good results. I guess, these add up limited abilities compared to the JV tool you refer.

Answer (score 0):

I use **Hijackthis** to scan the registry for settings installed by unwanted applications.

Also, sometimes it's best to get your hands dirty and touch **regedit** directly (Make sure you backup (export) before making changes though.  Use **Windiff** (from [Microsoft's Support tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=6EC50B78-8BE1-4E81-B3BE-4E7AC4F0912D&displaylang=en)) for looking up differences in the registry - between two **.reg** files).